# I never get RESULT_OK while taking a picture in my Android app but the picture is there

Tags: android

I have an Android application which uses a intent. here is the code:

```
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE= 1;
[...]
Uri imageUri = helper.createImageDestinationUri(null, filename);
[...]
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
```

and then I get the result here:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
        if (requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                    data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I have all the permissions which are needed.

**the strange thing:**
at the end the picture is always on my SD card but I never get the `RESULT_OK` result.

what is wrong there?

Comment: What device are you using?  Some Motorola devices like the Droid X have a tendency to return RESULT_CANCELED despite successfully taking a picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're checking requestCode for RESULT_OK

```
if (requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
```

when you should be checking resultCode

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
```

Comment: You saved me so much time